# Manual flush of messages to disk in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle the flush rates of data from the cache to disk while the cluster is up and running apart from setting the flush interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Kafka only exposes flush interval configs, in seconds `log.flush.interval.ms` or number of messages `log.flush.interval.messages`.

The flush mechanism is detailled in a couple of sections in the Kafka docs:

- [Os Flush Management](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#appvsosflush)
- [Linux Flush behavior](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#linuxflush)

Kafka actually recommends keeping explicit flush disabled (that's the default):

> We recommend using the default flush settings which disable
>   application fsync entirely. This means relying on the background flush
>   done by the OS and Kafka's own background flush. This provides the
>   best of all worlds for most uses: no knobs to tune, great throughput
>   and latency, and full recovery guarantees. We generally feel that the
>   guarantees provided by replication are stronger than sync to local
>   disk, however the paranoid still may prefer having both and
>   application level fsync policies are still supported.